# How do I deserialize an array of JSON data into a POJO using an abstract class?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, pojo

I am trying to map some JSON into a pojo.  I've seen how to do it with using information in the actual data, but it my case I don't really have anything identifying how the data is different, but I do know what the list is made up of. In the example below, I could be getting a list of prisoners or buildings, but in this case I know I am getting a list of prisoners.

I am given the JSON below (I know the nested *data* is odd, but I am being given the JSON, I have no control over it.)

```
{
    "data": [{
        "data": {
            "create_date": "2015-09-30",
            "building": "12",
            "dob": "2/11/1965",
            "gender": "M",
            "location": {
                "zip": "10459"
            },
            "name": {
                "first": "James",
                "last": "Bond"

            },
            "id": "45"
        },
        "uri": "/prisoner/45"
    }, {
        "data": {
            "create_date": "2015-09-27",
            "building": "12",
            "dob": "12/15/1985",
            "gender": "M",
            "location": {
                "zip": "10459"
            },
            "name": {
                "first": "Hans",
                "last": "Gruber"

            },
            "id": "56"
        },
        "uri": "/prisoner/56"
    }],
    "totals": {
        "total": 2,
        "page": 1
    },
    "links": [{
        "uri": "/prisoners?limit=2"
    }]
}
```

I have a *Data* object that contains a totals object and a links object.  I also have a Collection (in this case, a list) of a *Datum* object that contains the nested *Data* object array. The *Datum* object has a *Thing* abstract class along with a *Uri* string.  I have a *Prisoner* and a *Building* class extending *Thing*. In the above JSON, I know I am getting a list of prisoners.

My current code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Data data = mapper.readValue(responseJSON.toString(), Data.class);
```

If I go into *Datum* and change the *Thing* object to the *Prisoner* object, it works perfectly.  My question is how do I make it accept *Prisoner* or *Building* but still have the abstract *Thing* class in place, or at least make it so it can be more generic. I know I can make several *Datum* classes, but I believe there must be a way to have 1 Datum class.  I actually have dozens of different possibilities of data I could get, not just the 2 in my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean, you know what the types of Thing will be at the time that you read the value? Because in that case, you could parameterise Data (i.e. `Data<T extends Thing>`), and propagate the type parameter to Datum to specify the subclass of Thing that you have. And then you need to tell Jackson about the parameterised type when you call readValue, which can be done statically like this:

```
mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Data<Prisoner>>(){});
```

It can be done dynamically by constructing a parameterised type using the TypeFactory available from the ObjectMapper. Something like:

```
mapper.readValue("", mapper.getTypeFactory()
                           .constructParametricType(Data.class, thingSubclass));
```